# Yahoo api bbauth: Invalid (missing) src or appid

Tags: php, authentication, yahoo

I'm trying to load yahoo users' emails (but I'm stuck on the auth step):

```
define("APPID", 'dj***NQ--');
define("SECRET", '3***7');

// Include the proper class file
$v = phpversion();

if ($v[0] == '4') {
    include("includes/yahoo/ybrowserauth.class.php4");
} elseif ($v[0] == '5') {
    include("includes/yahoo/ybrowserauth.class.php5");

} else {
    die('Error: could not find the bbauth PHP class file.');
}
$authObj = new YBBauthREST(APPID, SECRET);
//echo APPID;
// If Yahoo! isn't sending the token, then we aren't coming back from an
// authentication attempt
if (empty($_GET["token"])) {
    // You can send some data along with the authentication request
    // In this case, the data is the string 'some_application_data'
    echo 'You have not signed on using BBauth yet<br /><br />';
    echo '<a href="'.$authObj->getAuthURL('some_application_data', true).'">Click here to authorize</a>';
    return;
}
```

But I get this error in the yahoo landing page:

> Invalid (missing) src or appid

So I'm guessing here is the problem?

```
echo '<a href="'.$authObj->getAuthURL('some_application_data', true).'">Click here to authorize</a>';
```

Should I replace 'some_aplication_data' with something else?

**Edit:**

I've also tried:

```
$callback = YahooUtil::current_url()."?in_popup";  
$auth_url = YahooSession::createAuthorizationUrl(APPID, SECRET, $callback);
echo '<a href="'.$auth_url.'">Click here to authorize</a>';
```

But it won't create the link or show errors (script dies).

Comment: If script dies, enable error logging in PHP and follow the error log. Also your other error message shows that you do not take care *where* it happens because the information has been removed from it and only a vague code-location follows instead providing as well the reported one. There is much room for improving your troubleshooting and I suggest you do that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Browser-Based Authentication, then you will need to make sure that you are registering your application as such. You need to get your application id and secret from https://developer.apps.yahoo.com/wsregapp/. This is different from where you would create a OAuth project. BBAuth has ONLY application id and secret.

In your case, it seems like the problem is that you have an invalid application id. Considering the other answer and discussion, it looks like that you have created a OAuth project instead of a Browser-Based Authentication Project.

Regarding your question "Should I replace 'some_aplication_data' whit something else?". According to the documentation, you would probably like to replace 'some_aplication_data' with session_id().

EDIT

I have tested your code with the the above recommendations, and it is working properly.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your reply, I got this other key/secrect and the auth works (this step, not the next ones... but i'll open another question)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the auth URL in this way

```
$callback = YahooUtil::current_url()."?in_popup";  
$auth_url = YahooSession::createAuthorizationUrl(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $callback);
```

REFERENCE
http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-userauth.html

Comment: the script crahes witout showing errors, so i dont know why... edited my question with the code i tried

Comment: You don't use the APPID . Its different from CONSUMER_KEY check this out http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/03/introducing_the_create_consumer_key_api/

Comment: I am not sure I understand... do I HAVE TO GENERATE the CONSUMER_key/secret in yahoo's site or in my code? Thanks for your time